# Delay future returns Error(shutdown) when polled

Tags: rust, timeout, rust-tokio

I'm rewriting the [`Forward`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/prelude/stream/struct.Forward.html) future from a `Stream` to a `Sink` adding a timeout on the reception of new items.
I'm using a [`Delay`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/timer/struct.Delay.html) future inside the `Forward` struct to keep track of the timeout, but the result is always an `Error(Shutdown)`.

From the [`timer::Error`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/timer/struct.Error.html) documentation I see that this should return only if the future is dropped but it should not be the case since it's still contained in the main struct.

This is a minimal test example from which I get the same result.

```
extern crate tokio; // 0.1.20

use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Delay;

fn main() {
    let mut delay = Delay::new(Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(3000));

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));

    match delay.poll() {
        Ok(Async::NotReady) => println!("Not ready"),
        Ok(Async::Ready(v)) => println!("Ready: {:?}", v),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

You can see a running example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dcb5b50d676e179c480ee8cba1432922)

I'm expecting to either receive an `Async:Ready(v)` where `v` is `()`.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Delay`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/timer/struct.Delay.html) works together with a [`Timer`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.2.11/tokio_timer/timer/struct.Timer.html) and the error here indicates that it was unable to register with one. While the docs sometimes assume that you're working within a tokio context, [they do mention this requirement](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/timer/):

> These types must be used from within the context of the [`Runtime`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html) or a timer context must be setup explicitly. See the [`tokio-timer`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer) crate for more details on how to setup a timer context.

If you wanted to avoid the error, it would be enough to run it inside a task:

```rust
fn main() {
    tokio::run(futures::future::lazy(|| {
        let mut delay = Delay::new(Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(3000));

        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));

        // "Not ready"
        match delay.poll() {
            Ok(Async::NotReady) => println!("Not ready"),
            Ok(Async::Ready(v)) => println!("Ready: {:?}", v),
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
        }

        Ok(())
    }))
}
```

However this will not transition to ready even if you wait more than 3000 milliseconds. If you want to use the Runtime's Timer you'll have to spawn it as a task:

```rust
fn main() {
    // "Ready: ()"
    tokio::run(
        Delay::new(Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(3000))
            .map(|v| println!("Ready: {:?}", v))
            .map_err(|e| println!("{:?}", e)),
    )
}
```